# How is this access token stored on the client, in FastAPI's tutorial "Simple OAuth2 with Password and Bearer"

Tags: http, swagger, fastapi

I'm pretty new to FastAPI and OAuth2 in general. I just worked through the tutorial ["Simple OAuth2 with Password and Bearer"](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/) and it mostly made sense, but there was one step that felt like magic to me..

**How does the access token get stored onto the client and subsequently get passed into the client's requests?**

My understanding of the flow is that it's basically

1. User authenticates with their username and password (these get POST'ed to the `/token` endpoint).
2. User's credentials are validated, and the `/token` endpoint returns the access token (`johndoe`) inside some JSON. (This is how the user receives his access token)
3. ???
4. User make a subsequent request to a private endpoint, like `GET /users/me`. The user's request includes the header `Authorization: Bearer johndoe`. (I don't think the docs mention this, but it's what I've gathered from inspecting the request in Chrome Developer Tools)
5. The authorization token is then used to lookup the user who made the request in (4)

Step (3) is the part that I don't understand. How does the access token seemingly get stored on the client, and then passed as a header into the next request?

#### Demo

When you run the code in the tutorial, you get the following swagger docs. (Note the *Authorize* button.)

[image]

I click Authorize and enter my credentials. (username: `johndoe`, password: `secret`)
[image]

And now I can access the `/users/me` endpoint.

[image]

Notice how the header `Authorization: Bearer johndoe` was automagically included in my request.

Last notes:

1. I've checked my cookies, session storage, and local storage and all are empty
2. The authorization header disappears if I refresh the page or open a new tab

I suspect Swagger is doing something under the hood here, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: How you store the access token is up to you - but localstorage is probably what most people do. You could just store it in a variable inside your javascript application; there is no need to persist it if you don't want it to survive a reload (which apparently swagger doesn't)

Comment: @MatsLindh I think you're misunderstanding my question. I'm asking how the example above stores the access token, not *how should I* store the access token.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from your indexed list of how the flow worked at the start. SwaggerUI keeps the reference internally in the library, unless you enable persistence. In that case it gets persisted to localStorage. You can see the code for pesisting authentication information here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/cc408812fc927e265da158bf68239530740ab4cc/src/core/plugins/auth/actions.js#L274

Comment: Ah, there it is. Thank you for helping me understand. If you feel like posting this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need persistence for the token you'd usually use localStorage or similar, but in SwaggerUIs specific case, the authentication information is kept internally in the library.

If you have enabled persistence SwaggerUI [will persistent the access token to localStorage](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/cc408812fc927e265da158bf68239530740ab4cc/src/core/plugins/auth/actions.js#L274):

```js
export const persistAuthorizationIfNeeded = () => ( { authSelectors, getConfigs } ) => {
  const configs = getConfigs()
  if (configs.persistAuthorization)
  {
    const authorized = authSelectors.authorized()
    localStorage.setItem("authorized", JSON.stringify(authorized.toJS()))
  }
}
```