# Fastapi OAuth2 token handeling. Missing Authorization header

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI with OAuth2PasswordBearer and RequestForm to implement a user login. The Login and retreiving the token works, but working with the token is not working for me.

I got this OAuth2PasswordBearer setup and /token function:

```
authmanager = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl='dauPP/token')

@router.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(db: AsyncIOMotorDatabase = Depends(get_database),
                                 form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    user = await authenticate_user(db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

This function checks the given username and password provided in a form against my MongoDB and this works great. It returns an access_token and token_type:
[image]

But if I try to access a managed router f.e. /home

```
@router.get("/home", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def get_home(request: Request, current_user: User = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.html", {
        "request": request, "title": "[D]ocument [A]dvanced [U]tility", "subtitle": current_user.username
    })
```

I receive a

> "Not authenticated"

response. Which would be good...if I didn't get the token beforehand.

I checked what the PasswordBearer is processing:

```
    async def __call__(self, request: Request) -> Optional[str]:
        print(request.headers)
        authorization: str = request.headers.get("Authorization")
        scheme, param = get_authorization_scheme_param(authorization)
        if not authorization or scheme.lower() != "bearer":
            if self.auto_error:
                raise HTTPException(
                    status_code=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                    detail="Not authenticated",
                    headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
                )
            else:
                return None
        return param
```

So I took a look at the contents of the request.headers and this is what I found (the "Cheking for...." is a print I added):

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59213 - "POST /dauAPP/token HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Headers({'host': '127.0.0.1:8000', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0', 'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'accept-language': 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1', 'sec-fetch-dest': 'document', 'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate', 'sec-fetch-site': 'none', 'sec-fetch-user': '?1'})
Checking for authorization in header...result:None
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59213 - "GET /dauAPP/home HTTP/1.1" 401 Unauthorized
```

I am quite new to web-dev so I might have fundamental flaws in my thinking, but I would assume, that returning an access token would result in the client/browser storing it and automatically adding it to its request headers in "Authorization". Do I have to do something with the token on client end? Might there be something wrong with the configuration, so that the Auth-Header gets cut off?

How I think it works:

```
get_home is called 
async def get_home(request: Request, current_user: User = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
--> dependency calling get_current_active_user

async def get_current_active_user(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user)):
--> dependency calling get_current_user

async def get_current_user(db: AsyncIOMotorDatabase = Depends(get_database), token: str = Depends(authmanager)):
--> dependency calls authmanager (OAuth2PasswordBearer)

which calls the def __call__ function mentioned earlier and here the header is missing.
```

Comment: "but I would assume, that returning an access token would result in the client/browser storing it and automatically adding it to its request headers in "Authorization"" - this assumption is wrong. It's your apps responsibility to store the token and transmit it for each request against an endpoint. If you're planning on using regular HTML and navigating through it as a user clicking links instead of as an API endpoint, you might want to look at using cookies instead of an HTTP header (which _are_ sent automagically by your browser).

Comment: would've been too good/easy. Thanks for the input, I was just confused because it works when using the authorization button from the swaggerui docs, but I guess there is a function behind that takes care of the header data.

Comment: Yes, since the swagger-ui can determine from the API signature that an Authorization header is required (which is what `OAuth2PasswordBearer` does, among other things), it knows that it can ask for and is expected to present that header. Since swagger-ui is not a common web standard as a part of HTTP, that's not something browsers should, or are able to, do. Cookies do serve that purpose, however - so you could use cookies if you want to do that. But API requests does not include cookies, and its far more common to use Authorization for those requests.

Comment: thank you for the elaboration. I know how to proceed from there. If you post it as an answer I will close the question with it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I would assume, that returning an access token would result in the client/browser storing it and automatically adding it to its request headers in "Authorization"

This assumption is where you're wrong. It's your apps responsibility to store the token and transmit it for each request against an endpoint. If you're planning on using regular HTML and navigating through it as a user clicking links instead of as an API endpoint, you might want to look at using cookies instead of an HTTP header (which are sent automagically by your browser).

The swagger-ui can determine from the API signature that an Authorization header is required (which is what OAuth2PasswordBearer does, among other things), it knows that it can ask for and is expected to present that header. Since swagger-ui is not a common web standard as a part of HTTP, that's not something browsers should, or are able to, do.

Cookies do serve that purpose, however - so you could use cookies if you want to do that. But API requests does not include cookies, and its far more common to use the Authorization header for those requests.

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69853435/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69769558/17865804) might be useful as well.

Comment: I want to use FastAPI with Azure authentication and I can't seem to find any documentation. All examples show `OAuth2PasswordBearer` but only with a restricted set of scenarios and not even https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security has any documentation of what parameters it takes and how it behaves.

Comment: @NeilG Ask a new question if you have a specific question - and provide examples and enough detail for someone to know what you're doing (a minimum example that shows the issue is really helpful) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a novice who faced a similar issue while trying to implement a website with directly with `FastAPI` both as backend and frontend (this is not optimal, but I have not learned `react.js` yet).

I managed to solve the issue after a few days. Here is what I can tell you from my limited experience.

Notice the following:

1. You have shown the source code of `OAuth2PasswordBearer`. This class expects you to store the token in a header whose key is `"Authorization"` and whose value is `"Bearer <token>"`.
2. Your `"/token"` route is creating a token and retrieving it, but that token is not being stored either as a header nor as a cookie.
3. You may want to split your route in two routes: `"/login"` and `"/token"`. Use `"/login"` to process the form data and store the authorization token, and use `"/token"` to authenticate user and generate an authorization token.
4. Once the user logs in in a website, you usually want to redirect the user to the a protected page. However, headers are lost during a redirect. Cookies are a special kind of header that are not lost during a redirect.
5. Because of that, your code can work in Swagger UI, but not when you actually test it by hitting the "submit" buttin in a login form of your website.
6. If you want to use redirect, then you can use the [fastapi-login package](https://fastapi-login.readthedocs.io/). Alternatively, you can create a custom class that inherits from `OAuth2PasswordBearer` and modify its `__call__` method to retrieve the authorization token from the cookies. I used the latter approach.
7. A benefit of using a secure cookie to store your token, is that it you can prevent a hacker attack using javascript. [Check this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROg1p0UZL0M)

The code below shows how to authenticate with token Bearer in a website using fastapi  both as backend and frontend.

Let us start with a file structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── individual.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── user.py
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── individual.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── login.py
│   │   ├── logout.py
│   │   ├── readme.py
│   │   ├── register.py
│   │   └── test_db.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── favicon2.ico
│   │   ├── logo.jpeg
│   │   └── styles.css
│   └── templates
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── individual.html
│       ├── layout.html
│       ├── login.html
│       ├── register.html
├── core
│   ├── hashing.py
│   ├── helpers.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── jwt.py
│   ├── oauth_extension.py
├── data
│   ├── create_db.sql
│   ├── my_database.db
│   ├── db_setup.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── README.md
```

Now, suppose you have a login form in `"login.html"`. When user submits this form, a post request is sent to the `"/login"` route.

The code below shows how to retrieve a token and store it both in cookies and headers. Afterwards, the user is redirected to `"/individual"` with a get request. Redirecting erases the headers but keeps the cookies, so in this case storing the token in the headers is actually useless.

```
# project/app/routes/login.py

from datetime import timedelta
from typing import Annotated
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException, status, Request, Depends
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, RedirectResponse
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from core.jwt import create_access_token, authenticate_user


templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="app/templates")
router = APIRouter(prefix="/auth", tags=["auth"])
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 30


@router.get("/login", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def render_login_page(request: Request):
    context = {
        "request": request,
        "display_version": "GET"
    }
    return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html", context)


@router.post("/login")
async def validate_login_form(
     request: Request, user_auth_form: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()]
     ):
    print("reached /login route.")

    # Verify user credentials and create auth token
    token = await get_token(request, user_auth_form)
    access_token = token.get("access_token")

    print("Valid user. Store token and redirect")

    redirect_url = "/individual"

    # This is how to store the token in headers, but it actually is lost in this case during redirect
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
    response = RedirectResponse(
         redirect_url, status_code = status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER, headers=headers
         )

    # Since headers are removed during redirection, but cookies are not, store token in cookie
    response.set_cookie(
         key='access-token', value=access_token, httponly=True, secure=True)
    return response


@router.post("/token")
async def get_token(
     request: Request, user_auth_form: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()]
     ):
        print("Reached '/auth/token' endpoint.\nValidating username and password")
        valid_user = await authenticate_user(user_auth_form)
        if not valid_user:
            raise HTTPException(
                 status_code = 400,
                 detail = "Incorrect username or password",
                 headers = {"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
                )
        # Valid user, generate temporary token
        access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
        access_token = create_access_token(
                        data = {"sub": user_auth_form.username},
                        expires_delta = access_token_expires
                        )
        return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

When the user reaches the `"/individual"` route, this is a protected route that expects a valid authentication token in the request. We declare that by using dependency injection like this: `Depends(verify_token)`. Below is the code for that individual.py:

```
# app/routes/individual.py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, Depends
from typing import Annotated
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from typing import Annotated
from app.models.user import TokenData
from core.jwt import verify_token

router = APIRouter()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="app/templates")

@router.get("/individual", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def index(request: Request, user_token: Annotated[TokenData, Depends(verify_token)]):
    context = {
        "request": request,
        "display_version": "GET",
        "username": user_token.username
    }
    print("Welcome to individual: ", user_token)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("individual.html", context)
```

When the `"/individual"` route is reached, the token should be retrieved from the `request` in order to authorize the user to access this route.
If the authorization token were stored in `request.headers`, we would be using `OAuth2PasswordBearer` to retrieve it. But in this case, we have reached this route through a redirect, which removes this header from the request. There is no `"Authorization"` key in request.headers.
Consequently, the `__call__` method in `OAuth2PasswordBearer` won't be able to retrieve the authorization token in this line, which returns `None`:

```
authorization: str = request.headers.get("Authorization")
```

To solve this issue, I got inspired [here](https://%20https://www.fastapitutorial.com/blog/fastapi-jwt-httponly-cookie/) to create a Class `OAuth2PasswordBearerWithCookie` that handles both cookies and headers. Alternatively, the fastapi-login package mentioned before provides a similar functionality.

Here is the implementation of the `OAuth2PasswordBearerWithCookie` class.

```
# project/core/oauth_extension.py

# Inspired by: https://www.fastapitutorial.com/blog/fastapi-jwt-httponly-cookie/

from typing import Optional, Tuple
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from fastapi.security.utils import get_authorization_scheme_param
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.status import HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN

from starlette.datastructures import MutableHeaders

class OAuth2PasswordBearerWithCookie(OAuth2PasswordBearer):
    """ Extends the OAuth2PasswordBearer class to retrieve password either from cookies or headers"""
    async def __call__(self, request: Request) -> Optional[str]:

        # Try to get auth field from headers (will be None during a redirect)
        authorization = request.headers.get("Authorization")

        if authorization is not None:
            scheme, param = get_authorization_scheme_param(authorization)
            if not authorization or scheme.lower() != "bearer":
                if self.auto_error:
                    raise HTTPException(
                        status_code=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                        detail="Not authenticated",
                        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
                    )
                else:
                    return None
            return param

        # No token in header. Try using cookie:

        # Get token from cookies
        token = request.cookies.get('access-token')
        if token:
            param = token
            return param
        else:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="Not authenticated",
                headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
            )
```

For the sake of completeness, below are other functions for authorization. Notice how the `oauth2_scheme` uses the custom class `OAuth2PasswordBearerWithCookie` defined above.

```
# project/core/jwt.py

from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status, Request
from jose import jwt, JWTError
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from app.models.user import TokenData
from data.db_setup import database
from core.hashing import Hasher
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, timezone
from typing import Annotated
from core.oauth_extension import OAuth2PasswordBearerWithCookie


# References:
#  https://www.jetbrains.com/guide/python/tutorials/fastapi-aws-kubernetes/auth_jwt/
# https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750#page-5

# To get secret key like this in bash, run:
# openssl rand -hex 32
# Secret key is used to sign the token by the server. Store is in your .venv, not here
SECRET_KEY = "09d25e094faa6ca2556c818166b7a9563b93f7099f6f0f4caa6cf63b88e8d3e7"
ALGORITHM = "HS256"
# ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 30

# https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/security/oauth2.py
# oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/auth/token")
# Notice: OAuth2PasswordBearer will not read cookies. Using my custom calss instead:
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearerWithCookie(tokenUrl="/auth/token")


async def authenticate_user(user_auth_form: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm) -> bool:
    """Returns True if username and password are registered in database"""
    # Find user in database
    user_row = await get_user_row_in_db(user_auth_form.username)

    if not user_row:
        print("username not found")
        # username not found in database
        return False

    if not Hasher.verify_password(
        user_auth_form.password, user_row.get("hashed_password")
        ):
        # password mismatch"
        print("invalid password")
        return False

    # User found and password does match.
    print("Valid user credentials!")
    return True


async def get_user_row_in_db(username: str) -> dict | None:
    """Queries database to retrieve username and hashed password from username"""

    desired_columns = ("id", "username", "hashed_password")

    # Get column names as 'col1, col2 ,...'
    concatenated_columns = ", ".join(
        [f"{column_name} " for column_name in desired_columns]
        )

    query = f"""
        SELECT {concatenated_columns}
        FROM users
        WHERE username = :username;
        """
    values = {"username": username}
    # Check if user is in database table 'users':
    row = await database.fetch_one(query=query, values=values)
    if not row:
        return None

    # Convert results to a dicionary with column names and value for each column
    return dict(zip(desired_columns, row))


def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: timedelta | None = None) -> str:
    """ Returns a JWT access token that expires within a time delta """
    to_encode = data.copy()

    # Set token creation timestamp
    current_time = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
    to_encode.update({"iat": current_time})

    # Set token expire timestamp
    if expires_delta:
        expire = current_time + expires_delta
    else:
        expire = current_time + timedelta(minutes=15)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})

    # Encode token
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(claims = to_encode,
                             key = SECRET_KEY,
                             algorithm = ALGORITHM
                             )
    return encoded_jwt


async def verify_token(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]) -> TokenData:
    """
    Decodes a JWT token and retrieves user
    We want to check the following:
    -1. Token Integrity:
        (a) Verify that the access token is valid,
        (b) hasn't expired,
        (c) and has been issued by your authentication server.
    -2. Token Claims: Ensure that the necessary claims are present in the payload.
    -3. User Existence: Check if the user identified by the claims (e.g., username) exists in your database.
    -4. Token Revocation: Depending on your security requirements, you might want to check whether the token has been revoked.
                       This can be important if you need to invalidate tokens before their natural expiration.
    """
    # Default exception if token validations fails
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )

    # Print (for debugging)
    print("*"*30,"\nToken verification in process")

    # Verify token claims and integrity
    try:
        # 1a, 1c: Check token is valid (1a), token has not expired(1b) and signed (1c)
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])

        # 2: Check payload contains username
        username: str = payload.get("sub")

        print("-->Token payload")
        print(" username: ", username)

        if username is None:
            # Could not find username in token
            raise credentials_exception

    except JWTError:
        print("Token verification failed")
        raise credentials_exception

    token_data = TokenData(username=username)

    # 3: Verify user exists in database
    user = await get_user_row_in_db(username=token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        print("Token verification in process")
        raise credentials_exception

    # TODO: 4: Token revocation

    print("Token verification succeded")
    print(token_data)
    return token_data
```

I have left a few print statements which you could use for debugging. I hope this helps you!